# Allow circular dependency between components in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have 2 components that depend on each other. When I try to do a `--prod` build which does aot, I get the error about circular dependencies being detected.

For example:

helloworld.component.html

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-4>
            <ion-card>
                <ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-title>Hello World!</ion-card-title>
                </ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-content>
                    <!--I want to be able to use this here... but it causes circular reference.-->
                   <testlibs-hellomoon></testlibs-hellomoon>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

HelloWorld.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TestLibsHelloMoonModule } from '../hellomoon/hellomoon.module';

import { TestLibsHelloWorldComponent } from './helloworld.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule, 
        IonicModule, 
        TestLibsHelloMoonModule //this causes circular dependency because we are injecting this module ( TestLibsHelloWorldModule ) into HelloMoonModule
    ],
    declarations: [TestLibsHelloWorldComponent],
    exports: [TestLibsHelloWorldComponent],
})
export class TestLibsHelloWorldModule {
    public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: TestLibsHelloWorldModule,
            providers: [],
        };
    }
}
```

And of course the opposite from the other side which is causing the circular dependency...

hellomoon.component.html

```
 <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-4>
                <ion-card>                    
                    <ion-card-header>
                        <ion-card-title>Hello World!</ion-card-title>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content>
                        <!--I want to be able to use this here... but it causes circular reference.-->
                       <testlibs-helloworld></testlibs-helloworld>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

hellomoon.module.ts

```
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { TestLibsHelloWorldModule } from '../helloworld/helloworld.module';
    
    import { TestLibsHelloWorldComponent } from './hellomoon.component';
    
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            CommonModule, 
            IonicModule, 
            TestLibsHelloWorldModule //this causes circular dependency because we are injecting this module ( TestLibsHelloMoonModule ) into HelloMoonModule
        ],
        declarations: [TestLibsHelloMoonComponent],
        exports: [TestLibsHelloMoonComponent],
    })
    export class TestLibsHelloMoonModule {
        public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
            return {
                ngModule: TestLibsHelloMoonModule,
                providers: [],
            };
        }
    }
```

I have read some articles and actually used Injection tokens as well as forwardRef for services before but i would I solve in this case where the components "use" each other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you think that would get rendered?  You're going to have an infinite recursion of one control in the other...That's the main reason for circular dependency detection.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it. I’ll be posting something today. Basically using entryComponents, ngtemplate, and componentFactoryResolver

Comment: @JudsonTerrell what is the usecase where you would want to "allow" circular dependency?

Comment: Why you are not using one module for both components?